# Using opacity mask on a border with only top border thickness set

Tags: wpf, expander, opacitymask

Hi I have been trying to override the `Expander` control in WPF to use a dividing line that sits "underneath" the header.

I have found an example of how to get an `Expander` to look like a group box, but I do not want the border to appear all the way around, only on the top side of the border.

The problem I face is that the border uses an opacity mask to deal with the border sitting under the header, but when I set the border thickness to 0,1,0,0 the opacity mask seems to fail. Setting any other border to 1+ seems to get it working again (1,1,0,0) but I am confused as to why this should make any difference and if there is any other way to achieve the desired result.

My existing XAML is as follows

```
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="6" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" />
                <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Padding="3,0,3,0">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ToggleButton Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="0" MinWidth="0"
                            Name="HeaderToggle"
                            IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" >
                            <ToggleButton.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Background="Transparent">
                                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="circle" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="15" Fill="{DynamicResource ButtonNormalBackgroundFill}" Stroke="DarkGray"/>
                                        <Ellipse Visibility="Hidden" HorizontalAlignment="Center" x:Name="shadow" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="13" Height="13" Fill="{DynamicResource ExpanderShadowFill}"/>
                                        <Path SnapsToDevicePixels="false" x:Name="arrow" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="#666" StrokeThickness="2" Data="M1,1 L4,4 7,1" />
                                    </Grid>

                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 1,4  L 4,1  L 7,4"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#666"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="shadow" Value="Visible"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </ToggleButton.Template>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="true"
                            TextElement.Foreground="{StaticResource GroupBoxHeaderBrush}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />


                <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" >
                    <Border.OpacityMask>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BorderGapMaskConverter}" ConverterParameter="7">
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="Header"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Border.OpacityMask>
                </Border>

            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                </Trigger>

            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

**EDIT:** By underneath I actually mean **behind**

Ok so I've photo-shopped an example of what I want to see visually, and now with the added complexity of a button in the far right corner.

[image: example screenshot]

I am happy to create a complicated mask to deal with additional controls but I just don't know how and I'm sure I dont actually need a border as just a single line would do.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated and please remember I want the background of the togglebutton and the header text to be TRANSPARENT so as to replicate the background of the parent control.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Ok I could get your screenshot translated to something like

[image]

Xaml:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
  <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="6" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Height="1"
                Margin="0 4 0 0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Height="1"
                Margin="0 4 0 0"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Fill="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
    <Border x:Name="Header"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Padding="3,0,3,0">
      <Grid Background="Transparent"
            SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition />
          <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton Name="HeaderToggle"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      MinWidth="0"
                      MinHeight="0"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded,
                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
          <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
              <Grid Background="Transparent"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="False">
                <Ellipse x:Name="circle"
                          Width="15"
                          Height="15"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Fill="{DynamicResource ButtonNormalBackgroundFill}"
                          Stroke="DarkGray" />
                <Ellipse x:Name="shadow"
                          Width="13"
                          Height="13"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Fill="{DynamicResource ExpanderShadowFill}"
                          Visibility="Hidden" />
                <Path x:Name="arrow"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Data="M1,1 L4,4 7,1"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="false"
                      Stroke="#666"
                      StrokeThickness="2" />
              </Grid>
              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                          Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="arrow"
                          Property="Data"
                          Value="M 1,4  L 4,1  L 7,4" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                          Value="true">
                  <Setter TargetName="circle"
                          Property="Stroke"
                          Value="#666" />
                  <Setter TargetName="arrow"
                          Property="Stroke"
                          Value="#222" />
                  <Setter TargetName="shadow"
                          Property="Visibility"
                          Value="Visible" />
                </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </ToggleButton.Template>
        </ToggleButton>
        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                          Margin="3,0,0,0"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ContentSource="Header"
                          RecognizesAccessKey="true"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                          TextElement.Foreground="Black" />
      </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="1"
                      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                      SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                      Visibility="Collapsed" />
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
              Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="ExpandSite"
              Property="Visibility"
              Value="Visible" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
              Value="false">
      <Setter Property="Foreground"
              Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I also did remove a few `Grid` `Rows` that were not being used and removed some `Grid` Attached properties that were being set of items that were not even children of `Grid`.

The main change is pretty much remove the `Border` and `OpacityMask` and just render `Rectangle`'s with a Height of 1 in the appropriate `Grid` Column. This way you are actually not rendering anything behind the header at all.

You can extend this concept ofc when you add the `Button` to the right. Just put it in it's own Grid Column and don't render a `Rectangle` in that Column

Comment: Sorry yes I meant behind, but the above option is not good enough as if I make this a common control I may want the control to be transparent in places and not have its own background, thus still leaving me with the problem of the border appearing through the header control. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how you expect this to look like please. Am still confused. If you combine both the behind and below approach I mentioned I'd think you'd have what you require but if it ain't so need to see a pic of your expected render

Comment: Sorry I'm struggleing to get a screenshot of what I want as I cannot achieve what I want. However your first suggestion works exactly as I would like right up until I make the toggle button and header background transparent, then the border just becomes visible through these controls. I know I need an opacity mask but I don't understand how to use it properly  and I don't understand why only having the top border thickness doesn't work. Thanks

Comment: @Kezza use paint or some other simple tool and just make a quick mockup of what you require. even if shabby just make sure it portrays your intentions, that should do just abt fine. Without a visual cue of your requirement I'm just not sure what to suggest.

Comment: ah-ha I see what you've done there. That will do the job, and I can probably figure out a custom control to re-use this style of expander. Thanks